# Nested for-loop only executing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JavaScript and jQuery to create a simple 40x40 grid.

Here's my nested for loop to do this:

```
function display_grid() {
  browser_grid = ''
  $visible_grid = $('#grid');

  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    $visible_grid.append('<div>');
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      $visible_grid.append("<div class='square'> </div>");
    }
    $visible_grid.append('</div>');
  }
}
```

I expect this to create 40 `div`s each with 40 `div`s inside each one of them. The browser shows only one single row with 40 `div`s.

```html
<div>
    <div class="square></div>
    <div class="square></div>
    <div class="square></div>
    ...
</div>
```

This is what I want it to do, but forty times. I'm not very experienced with JS, so I'm confused as to why the first loop isn't executing 40 times.

Comment: Note: The DOM API, that `.append()` depends upon, does not allow for injecting partial markup, such as `'<div>'` and `'</div>'` at separate times. It will forcibly *"fix*" the `<div>` into `<div></div>` and likely ignore the `</div>`. If you want to construct markup in parts, use a string and `.append()` the combined result.

Comment: I noticed that now that I fixed this. Should I just inject everything  into a string then append it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You are using the same global variable in both loops. Global variables should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a different variable name for the inner loop.

```
function display_grid() {
    browser_grid='';
    $visible_grid = $('#grid');

    for(var i=0; i<40; i++){
        $visible_grid.append('<div>');
        for(var j=0; j<40; j++){
            $visible_grid.append("<div class='square'> </div>");
        }
        $visible_grid.append('</div>');
    }
```

**Edit:** Added code.
Note that you should use the var keyword for counting variables in your for-loops.

What happened in your code is that after the 40 inner divs are created, the counter i is at 40 and the condition for the outer loop isn't true any longer, thus exiting that code block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys!

Changed the variable for my inner loop fixed the problem, but there was a problem with using .append()

Apparently it doesn't support partial markup, so instead I just appended all of my divs to a string instead.

```
for(var i=0;i<40;i++){
            browser_grid+='<div>';
            for(var x=0;x<40;x++){
                browser_grid+="<div class='square'> </div>";
            }
            browser_grid+='</div>';
        }

        $visible_grid.append(browser_grid)
```

After which, I appended the string to $visible_grid

This seemed to do what I wanted it to do. Just wanted to point it out for anyone else using the append method for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For info, maybe it's better written like this: `browser_grid='';
onegrid='';

onegrid+='<div>';
for(var x=0;x<40;x++) { onegrid+='<div class="square"> </div>'; }
onegrid+='</div>';

for(var i=0;i<40;i++) { browser_grid+=onegrid; }

$visible_grid.append(browser_grid)` Looks pretty similar but only use 2 loops with 40 iterations, instead of 40 loops with 40 iterations each, better perf I guess :)